# Is Bitrefill supported by lndhub?

Tags: lndhub

I have sent 3BTC to bitrefill.com via lndhub but my account balance is not reflected on the website but my lndhub is showing it. Am I missing something?

Comment: that's a LOT of money and you didn't send a small one first as a test?